# When a Battle Master fighter gets a critical hit and uses a maneuver that adds a superiority die to the damage, is that damage die doubled?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, critical-hit, combat-maneuver, battle-master

The Battle Master fighter has access to a number of maneuvers that add a superiority die to the damage roll. For instance, the Trip Attack maneuver says (PHB, p. 74):

> When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can expend one
>   superiority die to attempt to knock the target down. You add the
>   superiority die to the attack’s damage roll, and if the target is
>   Large or smaller, it must make a Strength saving throw. On a failed
>   save, you knock the target prone.

The Critical Hits rule states (PHB, p. 196):

> When you score a critical hit, you get to roll extra dice for the
>   attack’s damage against the target. Roll all of the attack’s damage
>   dice twice and add them together. Then add any relevant modifiers as
>   normal. [...] If the attack involves other damage dice, such as from
>   the rogue’s Sneak Attack feature, you roll those dice twice as well.

During our game, the fighter PC rolled a critical hit. He then wanted to use a superiority die to use the Trip Attack maneuver to trip the enemy. Based on the above rules, is the damage from the superiority die also doubled?

I'm assuming the answer is yes based on the last statement in the Critical Hits section, but I wanted to confirm.

Comment: [The linked question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79324/can-you-wait-to-add-optional-damage-dice-that-apply-on-a-hit-such-as-divine-smi) isn't actually a duplicate of this one (the linked one explicitly assumes that superiority dice added to an attack's damage are doubled on a crit, and asks if you can wait to use such abilities until after the attack roll is a nat. 20), though I suspect there are other questions that this is a duplicate of. I've reopened this question in the meantime.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [How does extra damage work for critical hits?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58118/how-does-extra-damage-work-for-critical-hits) Also related: [Is the damage from the Swords bard's Blade Flourish feature doubled on a crit?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/168103/is-the-damage-from-the-swords-bards-blade-flourish-feature-doubled-on-a-crit), [Does a spell critical do double damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53117/does-a-spell-critical-do-double-damage)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Yes

"If the attack involves other damage dice" sounds like a pretty solid indicator that "Superiority Dice" would be multiplied, if a maneuver were used that adds the result as damage.

While not applicable to everybody, that sounds like an awesome way to add extra damage to multiply (not that superiority dice are really game-breaking for additional damage) *after* learning that an attack hit... but I'd allow it, regardless.

Comment: Learning that an attack hit with a crit...and _then_ deciding to add in additional damage dice, is SOP for what paladins do with Divine Smite.