# Is Superiority Dice Damage Doubled Due To Assassinate?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, damage, fighter, critical-hit

Critical hits double all the dice rolls. Since Superiority Dice are dice rolls too, do they get doubled on a crit? That is, if a Fighter attacks, rolls a 20, and decides to use a combat maneuver, do they roll 2d8 for bonus damage?

Case in point: a Rogue3(Assassin)/Fighter3(Battle Master) multiclassed character deals a surprise round. Since they auto-crit due to Assassinate if they hit, they can also tack on a maneuver to add a guaranteed 2d8 damage (assuming the maneuver adds that damage in), on top of the 6d6 damage from sneak attack.

**Related**: [Does a Critical Hit when tripping also double the Superiority die?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76006/does-a-critical-hit-when-tripping-also-double-the-superiority-die), but I don't think it's a duplicate as this is concerning a more specific scenario with a multiclassed character.

Comment: I have no idea why that deleted Purple Monkey's comment. But yeah, is there some reason you think a critical from Assassinate is different to a normal critical?

Comment: @Miniman Not really. It just seemed neat and I wasn't sure of the RAI.