# Is the damage to the second target from the Green-Flame Blade cantrip also doubled on a critical hit?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, cantrips, critical-hit

I'm thinking of a concept of a spellcaster that fight in melee from the moment I re-read the "blade" cantrips (*green-flame blade* and *booming blade*), and realized that they can deal a lot of damage. Long story short, I re-read the Assassin subclass, and was thinking about how they interact with critical hits.

If it is obvious that the secondary damage from *booming blade* doesn't care about whether or not the initial attack was a critical hit, but how about *green-flame blade* (which basically gives you an automatic hit on another enemy)? How does *green-flame blade*'s secondary damage interact with critical hits?

**If I get a critical hit on the attack roll of *green-flame blade*, is the number of damage dice doubled for the damage to both targets? Or does it only double the damage dice for the first target?**

Comment: Related and possible duplicate on [How does extra damage work for critical hits?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58118/how-does-extra-damage-work-for-critical-hits)

Comment: @NautArch well would be a duplicate if I'd ask for the damages on the first roll I think

Comment: Yeah - related, yes.  Duplicate no.

Comment: @NautArch somehow the question is "does the second target is considered to be critical hited?" (not english speaker, so I don't know if the sentence is correct)

Comment: I tried to clean up your question a bit to focus on what I think is what you're asking. Is that correct?

Comment: A somewhat similar situation: "[Is the damage of a Battle Master fighter's Sweeping Attack maneuver doubled on a crit to the 2nd target?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/129376)"

Comment: Also related on [Can I sneak attack with Green-Flame Blade or Booming Blade?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/83147)

Comment: I'm confused about the question differentiating between "extra damage" (ostensibly extra damage on the same attack) and "damage that counts for crits". Am I misunderstanding the distinction the question is drawing? ...well, that's what I was going to say, but that distinction is actually being inaccurately introduced as a result of NautArch's edit. (In fact, "extra damage" on the same attack *is* doubled on a crit, but this question is asking about the damage to the second target that is *not* described as "extra" damage.) I've edited the question to match your initial one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [Player's Basic Rules](http://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/dnd/PlayerDnDBasicRules_v0.2.pdf#page=75):

> **Critical Hits**
>
> When you score a critical hit, you get to roll extra dice
>   for the attack’s damage **against the target**. Roll all of the
>   attack’s damage dice twice and add them together. Then
>   add any relevant modifiers as normal. To speed up play,
>   you can roll all the damage dice at once.
>
> For example, if you score a critical hit with a dagger,
>   roll 2d4 for the damage, rather than 1d4, and then add
>   your relevant ability modifier. If the attack involves other
>   damage dice, such as from the rogue’s Sneak Attack
>   feature, you roll those dice twice as well.  (PHB, p. 196; BR, p. 75)

It's an interesting edge case, but the rules are pretty clear.  The damage dice you roll against the target you were attacking are doubled by a critical hit, but there's no particular indication that damage that hits other targets is affected.  As such, the extra damage to a secondary target remains normal.

Additionally, while he's no longer a canonical rules source, we do have a [Crawford tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/854034196511117312) that confirms.

> The splash damage of green-flame blade isn't affected by the attack critting. Think of the attack as process X & the splash damage as Y #DnD

(thanks to @Medix2 on the tweet link)