# Magic Weapon Critical Hit Houserule

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, house-rules, critical-hit

My DM runs his game without allowing players access to homebrew options - *including Unearthed Arcana* - but something came up last season that gave me pause for thought.

A player’s character - *a 4th level Way of the Sun Soul Monk* - critically hit an enemy with a +1 hand-axe.
I was expecting the damage dice to be rolled at 2d6 plus some static damage as the enemy has no discernible weaknesses, but the DM called for 3d6.

I curiously asked him why it was 3, and he said:

> *A magic weapon with a + bonus adds that many of the weapons damage die to critical hits.*

My question is; **is this a house rule?** It hasn’t come up before (somehow) and I can’t find any mention of this in the rulebooks I have access to.

Comment: Has your DM previously run or played D&D 4th edition?

Comment: I think he has, yeah. Not something I’ve ever tried, though.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### This is a houserule

The section on [Critical Hits](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#CriticalHits) states:

> When you score a critical hit, you get to roll extra dice for the attack's damage against the target. **Roll all of the attack's damage dice twice** and add them together. Then add any relevant modifiers as normal. To speed up play, you can roll all the damage dice at once [...]

Note that you only roll the attack's damage dice twice, nothing else is doubled, such as modifiers, and no additional dice specifically occur when using a magic item. This is also explained in the following two questions:

- [How do critical hits and bonus damage interact?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139595)
- [How does extra damage work for critical hits?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58118)

Also, no part of the section on Magic Items states that they have this special property on a critical hit. Your GM saying that a +n longsword rolls (2+n)d6 is a houserule, and a rather strong one at that as it makes magic items *even more powerful* than they already are.

It also is rather strange because it means a 1d4 weapon will not benefit as much as a 1d12 weapon; normally one weapon could roll 2d4 on a crit and another 2d12, but with this houserule one could roll 5d4 and another 5d12. These are *much* farther apart in terms of their expected damage. Going from a difference of 8, to a difference of 20.

Your GM may be applying a rule that did exist in 4th-edition (thanks to [Carcer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/28402/carcer) for pointing this out):

> All magic weapons and implements give you an enhancement bonus to your attack rolls and damage rolls when you use them to make an attack [...]
>
> All magic weapons and implements deal one or more extra dice of damage on a critical hit. The number of extra dice is equal to the item’s enhancement bonus [...]

Comment: I checked on a hunch, and something very close to this particular mechanic *is* actually part of 4e's rules: "All magic weapons and implements deal one or more extra dice of damage on a critical hit. The number of extra dice is equal to the item’s enhancement bonus [...]" It is possible that the DM has previously run 4e and is carrying edition baggage.

Comment: @Carcer Oh that's a great point, I'd forgotten about that rule

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that 5e does have a mechanic of bonus dice on crit, but instead of being from magic weapons it's an Orc racial (Savage Attacks: +1 die) and a Barbarian class feature (Brutal Critical: +1 to +3 with level) for a max of 6d12 with a greataxe crit for an Orc barbarian.

Comment: Whether this makes the weapon actually stronger depends entirely on whether the damage replaces the normal damage bonus on all hits or is a bonus on top of that. In the former case assuming you've got a d12 weapon and a 50% chance to hit, no (dis)advantage, the expected damage increase of the magical weapon (ignoring the increased chance to hit) would be \$\frac{n \cdot 13}{40}\$ with the house rule vs the \$\frac{20 \cdot n}{40}\$ increase for the static bonus...

Comment: @fabian I see what you mean, but there's no reason to assume that the usual +x bonus to attack/damage rolls has gone away. Given that the OP didn't ask or mention anything about that and the +x bonus was already a thing in 4e it would be especially odd if the static +x bonus were removed. Earlier comments removed since I now understand what you meant.