# Is Spell Bombardment's die a damage die?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, damage

This stems from [Is the Spell Bombardment additional damage die subject to critical hit dice doubling?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131064/is-the-spell-bombardment-additional-damage-die-subject-to-critical-hit-dice-doub)

I re-read the description of Spell Bombardment

> When you roll damage for a spell and roll the highest number possible on any of the dice, choose one of those dice, roll it again and add that roll to the damage.

and noticed that the wording is different than other features adding damage dice, which usually say "extra".

Does the Spell Bombardment's die count as damage die? Or it is counted as a modifier, because the wording says "add that roll to the damage"?

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the Spell Bombardment additional damage die subject to critical hit dice doubling?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131064). Marking it because critical hits only double damage dice so this question is asking the same thing

Comment: @Medix2 this is not duplicate just because the (my) answer there stated that it will be doubled on critical. Please refer to FAQ https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7523/40999 for when a question is a duplicate. Simply put, this question ask an *obviously different* question than that question. If you can use the other post as reference why the answer is yes or no, please do so.

Comment: @StackLloyd I'm asking because I'm doubting the answer I've given in the linked question. I feel that this is a more fundamental question that can be used to further used as reference when other features grant reroll-and-add die.

Comment: @Vylix I'm saying you are asking the same thing. Asking "Does Spell Bombardment count as  damage dice" is the same as asking "Is Spell Bombardment doubled on a crit". This is because the only things that are doubled on a crit are damage dice

Comment: I've posted an answer to the current duplicate which addresses your issue