# Do abilities, spells, and magic items that give a user extra dice of damage benefit from the Critical Hit rules?

Tags: dnd-5e

Are abilities, spells and magic items that gives a user extra dice of damage susceptible to Critical Hit rules?

So does this counts with Hex, Hunter's mark, Colossus Slayer and even the extra 2d6 fire damage from something like Flame Tongue sword?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a spell critical do double damage?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53117/does-a-spell-critical-do-double-damage) and/or [How does extra damage work for critical hits?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58118/how-does-extra-damage-work-for-critical-hits)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of either of the two. Where in the answers does it say?

Comment: Have you read the rules?  What about the rules do you find unclear?  I find your question unclear.

Comment: @daze413 It seems to me that both duplicates answer this question with a resounding "yes". How is this not answered by those already?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie "Yes" is the correct answer but they aren't duplicates. The first covers only spell attacks (e.g. firebolt), and the second covers an "attack rider" that has nothing to do with the attack itself (e.g. Giant Spider poison). This question is not asking about either. Granted, this question is poor because it can be answered simply by reading the PHB on Critical Hits, but it's not a duplicate, in my opinion.